# xpath get child node excluding parent

Tags: xpath

I'm looking for an xpath that will give me a child node only if the parent node doesn't equal a specific value.   For example if I have an xml like the following:

```
<Grandpa><Dad><Son /></Dad><Son /></Grandpa>
```

I want to return the Son element outside the Dad element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Xpath selects those `Son` elements whose parent element is not named `Dad`:

```
//Son[local-name(..) != 'Dad']
```

So, applied to this XML:

```
<Grandpa><Dad><Son a="1"/></Dad><Son a="2"/></Grandpa>
```

It will select:

```
<Son a="2"/>
```